# Are there any open source web applications out there with good QUnit (or JSUnit) test cases?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

For a research project we are looking for JavaScript-based web applications that come with unit tests in QUnit or JSUnit.

Our search has only retrieved very simple uncomplete qunit test cases for JavaScript code on the web so far. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at jQuery? https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/test

Comment: we are looking for web applications, not JS libraries.